# Valgrind report read error on =operator with nested shared_ptrs

Tags: c++, c++11, valgrind, shared-ptr

I have this simple code

```
#include<memory>

class SLLNode{
        public:
                SLLNode(const int& d){
                        data_ = d;
                }
                std::shared_ptr<SLLNode> next_;
                int data_;
};

int main(){

        std::shared_ptr<SLLNode> head(new SLLNode(1));
        head->next_.reset(new SLLNode(2));
        *head = *(head->next_);
        return 0;
}
```

Valgrind is complaining about invalid read in my case.

```
==17312== Invalid read of size 4
==17312==    at 0x108EF3: SLLNode::operator=(SLLNode const&) (test_shared_ptr.cpp:3)
==17312==    by 0x108DA3: main (test_shared_ptr.cpp:16)
==17312==  Address 0x5b7dd50 is 16 bytes inside a block of size 24 free'd
==17312==    at 0x4C3123B: operator delete(void*) (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==17312==    by 0x109511: std::_Sp_counted_ptr<SLLNode*, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2>::_M_dispose() (shared_ptr_base.h:376)
==17312==    by 0x1090DF: std::_Sp_counted_base<(__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2>::_M_release() (shared_ptr_base.h:154)
==17312==    by 0x109061: std::__shared_count<(__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2>::operator=(std::__shared_count<(__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2> const&) (shared_ptr_base.h:703)
==17312==    by 0x108E9A: std::__shared_ptr<SLLNode, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2>::operator=(std::__shared_ptr<SLLNode, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2> const&) (shared_ptr_base.h:1034)
==17312==    by 0x108EC4: std::shared_ptr<SLLNode>::operator=(std::shared_ptr<SLLNode> const&) (shared_ptr.h:93)
==17312==    by 0x108EEE: SLLNode::operator=(SLLNode const&) (test_shared_ptr.cpp:3)
==17312==    by 0x108DA3: main (test_shared_ptr.cpp:16)
==17312==  Block was alloc'd at
==17312==    at 0x4C3017F: operator new(unsigned long) (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==17312==    by 0x108D5C: main (test_shared_ptr.cpp:15)
```

The command I use is:

```
valgrind --tool=memcheck ./test_shared_ptr
```

The =operator seems to cause this issue only when I use nested shared_ptr.
I was expecting the data from the ptr head to be released and replace by the one from the ptr head.next_, but it appears that something else is happening since I have this invalid read.
I want to replace the data pointed by head (and not head itself) since this head ptr could be a copy of another shared_ptr of head.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The implicitly defined assignment operator looks like this:

```
SLLNode& SLLNode::operator=(const SLLNode& other) {
  next_ = other.next_;
  data_ = other.data_;
  return *this;
}
```

In your example, `other` is `SLLNode(2)`, and it's only kept alive by a reference from `head->next_`. `other.next_` is `NULL`.

The first assignment above sets `head->next_` to `NULL`, which causes `SLLNode(2)` to be destroyed, and leaves `other` a dangling reference. The next line exhibits undefined behavior by way of accessing an object after its lifetime has ended.

Comment: Thx, I see what is happening. Redefining the operator= so the data_ assignment occurs before the next_ assignment work as a fix but is there any other way (maybe cleaner)?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? With this approach, if you have a linked list like `head->A->B->C->D` and you assign `*head = *C;`, you'll end up with the list `head->D`; nodes `A`, `B` and `C` will all be destroyed. Is this what you want?

Comment: I am just trying to implement a singly linked list. I used head in my example but the idea was just to remove any node (head in this case). So it would be head->A->B and if I give A to delete I should have head->B

Comment: sorry I didn't explain properly. I am trying to write a function that would take a shared_ptr to a node in order to delete it. So I have to make sure that the previous one is now pointing to the next one. so given this list head->A->B if I pass the shared_ptr to A to my function the list should be head->B in the end

Comment: Normally, you would delete a node by doing `previous_node->next_ = this_node->next_`. I'm not sure why you are trying to assign whole nodes.

Comment: since it's a singly linked list I don't have access to my previous node, on to the on to delete (and the next one of course)

Comment: Ah, I think I understand what you are trying to do. To "delete" a given node, you copy the data over from the next node, then delete that next node. That would work for everything except the very last node, of course.

Comment: Yes, that is what I am trying to do. And yes indeed it won't work for the last node.